# map for using sass in bootstrap for bower project

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bower

I'm kind of confused. This is my project structure

[image]

installing bootstrap using bower and some file and directory what direction should I follow to using sass in this kind of structure: for example I mean

1. install grunt
2. grunt to your project
3. add sass file what ever your want
4. ...

I see a lot of ways and you know many of them do not match with my project structure. some one said grunt some one else said bootstrap sass and compile your project and more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### this article by css tricks is the MAP

### [Gulp for Beginners](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/)

1-install gulp globally
2-install gulp in your project
note-gulp is very very flexible with paths and project structures
3-you need two folder app-dist
4-add file gulpfilel.js
5-install sass plugin in gulp
6-write a task and run it ! 
7-just simple ?!!

[image]